# Why are updates not getting saved in database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following code to save dat in database:

```
public void SaveCustomer(customer_table customer)
{
    if (customer.customerID == 0)
    {
        context.customer_table.Add(customer);
    }
    else 
    {
        customer_table dbEntry = context.customer_table.Find(customer.customerID);

        if (dbEntry != null)
        {
            dbEntry.customer_name = customer.customer_name;
            dbEntry.is_married = customer.is_married;
            dbEntry.cash_amount = customer.cash_amount;
            dbEntry.tax_calculated = customer.tax_calculated;
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, the table in SQL server is not getting updated. Please help.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Do the `if` clauses in your `if-else` actually fall through?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to save this: 'dbEntry.tax_calculated = customer.tax_calculated;' and it has the desired value when I debug it on that line

Comment: Are first chance exceptions turned on? Perhaps `context.SaveChanges` is throwing an exception?

Comment: use this                                                                                                                     db.Entry(customer_table ).State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the change tracker to see what has been added/deleted/modified prior to calling save changes. You must not be adding/deleting/modifying anything.

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: It wasn't me, sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply save the customer that you are referencing, instead of loading the customer from the database again and then modifying the values.

```
public void SaveCustomer(customer_table customer)
{
    if (customer.customerID == 0)
    {
        context.customer_table.Add(customer);
    }
    else
    {            
        context.customer_table.AddOrUpdate(customer);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It might be a detached object. Using `Find()` will return the cached attached object and otherwise get an attached object from the database.

Comment: So what does this line do context.customer_table.AddOrUpdate(customer);

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent. But that doesn't answer the problem at hand because evidently he's already doing that.

Comment: I don't see why you would load the entity/get the entity from the cache and update that entity with values when you already have that entity that you are passing to your method. Any logic like setting up the entity should not be done in this method. It's simply a save.